I am having issue with "eval" while trying to build a command inside foreach loop
So there's an array which contains all the from and to registers to create path groups inside Innovus Implementation System, but I don't understand why it doesn't create a path group named r2m. Any suggestions?
foreach groupPathName [array names CDNC_PATH_GROUPS] {
    set run_group_path 1
    if {[regexp all_registers $CDNC_PATH_GROUPS($groupPathName)] && [sizeof_collection [all_registers]] == 0} {
        set run_group_path 0
    }
    if {$run_group_path} {
        eval group_path -name $groupPathName $CDNC_PATH_GROUPS($groupPathName)"
    }
}

Initially I thought it's not creating that path group because of command length truncation of Innovus, but that's not the case, I tried to shrink the register names, but still it doesn't create. Is there any other way to take care of this?

Does $CDNC_PATH_GROUPS(r2m) exist?
Does the value of $CDNC_PATH_GROUPS(r2m) include the string all_registers?
Why are you maintaining the run_group_path variable?   Instead, you could use continue in the first if statement, or you could change the second if statement to a elseif statement.

The eval statement has the wrong number of double quotes. Why do you need eval anyway?

... and there is a single quote " at the end of $CDNC_PATH_GROUPS($groupPathName)"

check if r2m  path group exists in your array puts [array names CDNC_PATH_GROUPS]

does:

$CDNC_PATH_GROUPS($groupPathName) contain a list of names?
group_path require not one list but one or more individual names?

If yes, then use
group_path -name $groupPathName {*}$CDNC_PATH_GROUPS($groupPathName)
# ..............................^^^

See Argument expansion in the Tcl syntax rules.
